# bbpress code to display total number of topics

Tags: wordpress, count, forum, bbpress

I am using wordpress to design a website and I integrated bbpress plugin. I will like to display the total number of created topics at the frontend, but I can't find how to do this. I tried using

```
bbp_get_forum_topic_count();
```

but it displays total number of topics in a selected forum. I don't want this, I want to display the total number of all the topics created on the site.
Any help will me much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use WordPress core function 'wp_count_posts' like this:

```
$count = wp_count_posts('topic');
echo $count->publish;
```

More information about this function is available here: [wp_count_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts).